# Understanding TIFF file georeferencing

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, elevation, osr

I am new to maps and ArcGIS field, and having some issues understanding the used georeferencing systems, I have a dem.tif file, when extracting information I get X and Y in very large number, I used osgeo osr and GDAL to transform (X,Y) to longitude-latitude pairs. I can access the elevation information using (X,Y) as follows:

```
Elevation of  767095.1  and  3902560.4 is: 24
world coordinates is :  (35.934841026164186, 35.23056387649884, 0.0)
```

The issue is that I can not understand what is the coordinates system which gives me (767095.1,3902560.4) and how it's related to the world coordinates system.

I used the Python osr library to get the Spatial Reference:

```
old_cs= osr.SpatialReference()
old_cs.ImportFromWkt(ds.GetProjectionRef())
```

and I have compared it to the world coordination couldn't find the relation:

1. world coordinates (new-cs)

*PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 36N",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",33],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]*

2. old-cs

*ds.GetProjectionRef(): GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],*

Ultimately I need this information to convert from a camera coordinates to another known coordinate where I can get the elevation data.

Comment: Since you are using Python I would suggest opening your ```dem.tif``` using the rasterio library (check this out: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html). This will give you information about the spatial bounds and the transformation between pixel and spatial locations.

Comment: You seem to be conflating reprojection and georeferencing. Georeferencing is the process of assigning corner coordinates, scaling and rotation to model ground locations of an image. Projection (and more generally, coordinate system transformation) is the process of converting between known coordinate systems.. For the former you need to know what pixel corresponds to a true location (for several points), for the latter you just need a projection library.

Comment: There is no "world coordinates system". There are many [coordinate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system), some are [projected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection), some are [geographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system).